# Machine learning algorithm to predict next value

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to predict the next value of a series.  What the best machine learning / algorithm I need to use?

I have for example this matrix:

```
 [114, 160, 60, 27]
[74, 97, 73, 14]
[119, 157, 112, 23]
```

and I want to predict this values:

```
 [114, 160, 60, 27 , **80 , 90**]
[74, 97, 73, 14 , **10 , 15**]
[119, 157, 112, 23 , **50 , 48**]
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand well your question, in your case :

`X = [114, 160, 60, 27] and Y = [80,90]
     [74, 97, 73, 14]           [10,15]
     [119, 157, 112, 23]        [50,48]`
And you want to fit a machine learning algorithm on this data ?

You could use any supervied learning algo like regression or SVM using X as input and Y as output.

You could also use iterative learning : you learn a predictor `f` a step ahead with :

`X = [114, 160, 60, 27] and Y = [80]
     [74, 97, 73, 14]           [10]
     [119, 157, 112, 23]        [50]`

You do the prediction one step ahead :

`f(X) = [pred1]
        [pred2]
        [pred3]`

After that you incorporate the prediction in the input, so now you have :

`Xbis = [114, 160, 60, 27, pred1] and Yter = [90]
        [74, 97, 73, 14,pred2]               [15]
        [119, 157, 112, 23,pred3]            [48]`

And you train another predictor `fbis` on Xbis and Ybis.

So at the end, you have two predictors `f` and `fbis`, both of them predicting one step ahead. It enables you to do prediction two step ahead.
Of course, you will need more data to train a good predictor.

More generally, if you want to do time series prediction, you can use "the window method" which is a general method to create your input and output from the time series to then learn a predictor.

Note also that LSTM are quite use in time series prediction and seems to give pretty good results.

Hope this helps !!

Benoit

Comment: Who to write it ?

Comment: You can find an example on this page : http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/